# Textline Box Files Tesseract 4.0

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I think I must be fundamentally misunderstanding something here, but the documentation for [Making Box Files 4.0](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Making-Box-Files---4.0) states:

> The required format for LSTM 4.0alpha is still the tiff/box file pair, except that the boxes only need to cover a textline instead of individual characters.

However it then goes to link to a [Box File](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/files/1935824/eng.Times_New_Roman.exp0.box.txt) which has character-by-character boxes, e.g:

```
T 112 4663 140 4696 0
e 140 4662 160 4686 0
s 163 4662 179 4686 0
s 182 4661 198 4686 0
e 200 4661 220 4685 0
r 221 4662 238 4685 0
a 239 4661 260 4685 0
c 261 4661 281 4685 0
t 281 4661 296 4691 0
```

Can someone explain why this seems to be a discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

There are tab characters (\t) that mark ends of lines. If you read further down that documentation, it will state just that.

```
T 112 4663 140 4696 0
e 140 4662 160 4686 0
s 163 4662 179 4686 0
s 182 4661 198 4686 0
e 200 4661 220 4685 0
r 221 4662 238 4685 0
a 239 4661 260 4685 0
c 261 4661 281 4685 0
t 281 4661 296 4691 0
  296 4661 311 4696 0
O 311 4661 344 4696 0
C 347 4661 377 4696 0
R 378 4661 414 4695 0
     414 4694 415 4695 0
A 110 4575 146 4609 0
b 145 4574 167 4610 0
o 171 4573 193 4598 0
u 195 4573 219 4596 0
t 220 4573 234 4603 0
     234 4602 235 4603 0
```

Comment: I understand that. But the boxes to me still seem cover individual characters (e.g. the first box is "112 4663 140 4696" , which covers the letter "T"), rather than a whole line?

Answer (score 0):

The LSTM training does not really need individual char coordinates.

The problem arises from not very good wording in tesseract wiki, [old textline box example file](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/files/1935824/eng.Times_New_Roman.exp0.box.txt) and the fact that "Multiple formats of box files are accepted by Tesseract4".

Please see [#2357](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/2357) for details and examples provided by @shreeshrii.